# java - Flutter with output error, A value of type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I was copying the code from a tutorial, I just copied the exact SAME thing and the guy from the tutorial doesn't have issues, but I do so idk what is going on, I was imagining that maybe is because that I have the latest version of Flutter or something like that, so PLEASE I NEED HELP NOW. I have gradle with 21 version.
Here is my code: (The errors are mark on the code)

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  File _image; //<------------------marks wrong and tells me to put a late before File
  bool _loading = false;
  List _output; //<------------------marks wrong and tells me to put a late before List

  pickImage() async {
    var image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if(image != null) return null;

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
    classifyImage(_image);
  }
  pickGalleryImage() async {
    var image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if(image != null) return null;

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
    classifyImage(_image);
  }

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    loadModel().then((value){
      // setState((){});
    });
  }

  classifyImage(File image) async{
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(path: image.path, numResults: 2, threshold: 0.5, imageMean: 127.5, imageStd: 127.5);

    setState((){
      _output = output; //The other issue is here, it tells me to write a ! on the output
      _loading = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: These are all null-safety features from dart which is enabled by default in new flutter projects. [Here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq) a pretty awesome page from flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) feature in the dart language. We have to explicitly tell the compiler if we want to make a value nullable.

For instance, just writing `File _image;`, says that _image's value can never be null. But there is no initial value assigned. That means `_image` will be assigned the value `null`.
This is a contradiction.

Two most common solutions for this.

1. Define the variables with a `?`, so dart knows that value can be null.
   Like this: `File? _image;`
2. Define the variable with the `late` keyword. This will tell the compiler that the value of `_image` will be initialized sometime later but before it is used and once initialized it can't be `null` again.
   This is how we can use it: `late File _image;`

So, if we don't have an initial value for a variable during it's declaration, we either make it nullable (using `?`) or the `late` keyword.

- If the value can be null, use `?`.
- If the value can't be null, use `late`. (But remember to initialize first, there can be runtime errors if the `late` feature is not used properly.)

```dart
// option 1:
File? _image; // this makes more sense since _image can be null

// option 2:
late File _image;
```

Same for `_output`.

I'll encourage you to read flutter official docs and other resources about null safety in dart.